# How can I get my images to fade out?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition, fade

On my [portfolio page](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/things/) I currently have on the images:

```
.collection-type-gallery #slideshow .slide img:hover {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

But its not fading back out. They only fade in. How can i get it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `:hover` from transition declaration:

```css
.collection-type-gallery #slideshow .slide img { /* Set the transition on img without hover */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
}

.collection-type-gallery #slideshow .slide img:hover{opacity:1;} /* apply opacity change on hover */
```

The problem is you attached the transition only to `img:hover`, so when you take your mouse off it, the transition doesn't apply anymore, set the transition on the `img` without `:hover`, then only assign `opaicty:1` to `img:hover`

Comment: is there a way to add it to my homepage slideshow, so they fade nicer?

Comment: @JeffDowell what do you mean?

Comment: on this page http://jeffreydowellphotography.com i would like the images to fade into each other slower, a nicer transition. they change quickly and kinda flicker

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36048/discussion-between-yotam-omer-and-jeff-dowell)